# There is any way to use the same file from 2 PCs?

Tags: blend-files

I want to "host" a blender file. I mean if antoher pc edit it I can see it from my PC. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use some cloud. I have files on cloud and every time i make some changes it uploads to cloud and then it download the changes to the file on my other computer.

Comment: Thanks. Its cool but not perfect.

Comment: Please add more to your question, what do you expect and **why** this answer e.g. *is not perfect* instead @ÁdámKara (funny enough that my comment is longer than your question body)...

Comment: The proble is I want to make this blend file to be like a server

Comment: So you want to have a file that is open for a number of people who are working on it at the same time? Kind of google document

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best way is to have a master file, and split your scene into multiple assets (save as dedicated .blend), then use [File > Link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/index.html) to show them into the master file.

The assets files can be directly saved on your local network (shared folder on your computer or shared network drive folder, can be slow), or cloud folder like Fowl suggest, or even better, using a versionning system like SVN.

Note that linked libraries have some limitations, but Blender users can hope for changes soon, [with overrides](https://code.blender.org/2020/01/2020-blender-big-projects/).